# What is the difference between feed, posts and statuses in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to write a program that retreives a given user's "statuses" (and by statuses I mean the things he posted himself, anything he wrote as I'm mostly interested in textual statuses)

I cannot figure out the difference from the documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ so I don't know which connection type to use; feed, posts or statuses

(Another thing I noticed is that statuses requires an access_token while the other 2 require the access_token only for non public stuff)

Thanks

Answer (score 53):

This is documented on the [User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user) object of the Graph api. And, as of the Graph API v2.6, there is basically one main endpoint from which you get posts from a user.

- [`/{user-id}/feed`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/feed) includes all the things that a user might see on their own profile feed; this includes, e.g., shared links, checkins, photos and status updates. This *also* includes posts made by friends on the user's profile.

  The following endpoints return subsets of the above:

  - `/{user-id}/posts` returns the posts created by the user (on their own profile or the profile of a friend), and it may include any kind of content such as shared links, checkins, photos and status updates.
  - `/{user-id}/tagged` returns the posts created by friends and shared on the users's profile.

By default each returned post only includes the `story` field with a textual description of the post. But you can use the `?fields=...` parameter to request as many [Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/post) fields as you want.

You'll need the `user_posts` permission for any of these to work.

*The following endpoints are deprecated:*

- [`/{user-id}/statuses`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/statuses) returns *only* status updates posted by the user on their own profile. [removed after Graph API v2.3]
- [`/{user-id}/home`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/home) returns a stream of all the posts created by the user and their friends, i.e. what you usually find on the “News Feed” of Facebook. [removed after Graph API v2.3]

Comment: The answer of whether /posts includes posts made on the freinds' wall is 'yes.'

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is weird, but there is not `/posts` endpoint definition in Facebook's User docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user). Though it works fine.

Comment: Weird indeed, I've updated again the answer with the most complete info I could found from the recent documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I've found one more difference between /statuses and /posts. /statuses are just text statuses (it doesn't include shared links)

Answer (score 0):

Feed - https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed - gives you the user's feed - meaning the posts he sees when he is visiting facebook (friends important posts) - notice that facebook filters only things it's algorithm marks as significant to the user and not everything.

Status - what the user posts on his own wall

Posts - what the user posts - including on other people's walls

Comment: I got the sense that posts is what is posted on the user's wall, either by himself or others.
Do you have any link/documentation to support what you're saying?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ - look at /posts - if you click it you will get your own /me/posts - if you look closesly you'll see that it contains both what you wrote on your own wall (status) and what you wrote on others

Comment: The posts connection also seems to show posts made by others where you also have been tagged.

Comment: The information contained in this answer seems to be wrong. See my answer.