# Facebook graph API: Posts made by user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can I generate a list of things a user has posted? /id/posts only returns that users wall. I can't find a query that generates posts made by the user anywhere on Facebook (id friends walls).

I also tried this in FQL, to no avail:

```
select message from stream where source_id in (select uid1 from friend where uid2=me()) and actor_id=me()
```

Comment: The user has posted on his wall or everywhere?

Comment: Everywhere - sorry, unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the user feed. There you will found every (public) post, comment, photo tag, etc. If you only need status posts, you can check where the attribute **"type"** is equals to **status**.

To see how it works, you can use the [Facebook Graph Explorer Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). There you can make Graph Api calls and see the answer for that. After grant an valid access token (click on the button and give the **user status** and **friend user status** permissions), call (GET) **/me/feed** and check the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don´t use FQL if there is an easier way with the Graph API. In that case, it would be "**`/me/posts`**". You can try it in the **Graph API Explorer**:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fposts

Here´s a very good explanation about the posts connection and oter possibilities to get the feed and whatnot: [What is the difference between feed, posts and statuses in Facebook Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214535/what-is-the-difference-between-feed-posts-and-statuses-in-facebook-graph-api)

See the answer with the highest voting:

> The /posts api returns the posts created by the user (on her own wall
>   or the wall of a friend), and it may include any kind of content such
>   as shared links, checkins, photos and status updates.

Compare with the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

You can try other connections too but technically it should be exactly what you need. You also should not need more than the "**read_stream**" permission.

EDIT: However, i just tested it in the Graph API Explorer and only get the postings on my own wall, so i assume that there is a bug in the API.